# Adding rows to a tableView with custom section headers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a problem in that when I add rows (with animation) to my table, the section headers do not move. I create the section headers in viewDidLoad like so:

```
CGRect header = [self.tableView rectForHeaderInSection:0];
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:headerFrame];
[label setText:@"---"];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[label setFont:headerFont];
[label setTextColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
[self.tableView addSubview:label];
[label release];
```

Am I supposed to add them in a different manner? (And yes I realize that these are custom table headers, that's how I want them)

And I have a user add rows by using a picker. The rows are added like so:

```
    NSIndexPath* path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:chan.channel_number inSection:section_number];

    NSArray* row_to_add = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:path , nil];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:row_to_add withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
```

And the row gets added just fine, but my header views dont budge. How can I make my headers reposition themselves?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a real header title. You can use the delegate method tableView:viewForHeaderinSection: and return a UILabel.

Comment: Have you tried this?  This will let you use your custom labels.

Answer (score 0):

If you use:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Everything should be fine

Comment: I have custom headers for a reason

Comment: Ok i just thought because you asked: "Am I supposed to add them in a different manner?" Maybe add it to your question to avoid confusion. Not familiar with custom tableview headers, so good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try `-reloadSections:withRowAnimation:`. This shall cause a reload of your section and its header and footer views.